# fetchColumn error on PDO while trying to get number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-num-rows

I'm trying to move to PDO.

I want to do a classic query for checking number of rows, in mysql I would have done `mysql_num_rows_result` but I've read somewhere that in PDO it does not work.

So I've tried with a fetch column using the following code :

```
global $bdd;
            $login = $bdd->query("SELECT
                   COUNT
                    FROM spb_clients_acces_compte,
                         spb_clients_infos_generales
                    WHERE spb_clients_acces_compte.spb_clients_acces_compte_e_mail = '{$email}'
                    AND spb_clients_acces_compte.spb_clients_acces_compte_pwd_md5 = '{$pass}'
                    AND spb_clients_acces_compte.spb_clients_acces_compte_admin = 1");
            $reponse = $bdd->fetchColumn();
            if ($reponse == 0):

            elseif ($reponse == 1):

            else:
            endif;
            var_dump($reponse);
```

This return to me :

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchColumn() in C:\wamp\www\spb2016\admin\core\login.php on line 20

Line 20 is :     `$reponse = $bdd->fetchColumn();`

I've tried many things with no success

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: *"I would have done mysql_num_rows_result but I've read somewhere that in PDO it does not work."* - Exactly. You can't go mixing different APIs and we don't know if you're using the same one to connect with. If you're not connecting with PDO, well that's an issue.

Comment: [Get the number of rows with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31569733/1011527)

Comment: This `SELECT
                   COUNT` if you're wanting to use that function and you don't have a column called `COUNT`, then it's `COUNT(col|*)`

Comment: connexion is `$bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=183867brwzl", "root", "");`

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php   `fetchColumn` is a method of the PDOStatement object, which is what you get BACK from your query call. `$bdd` is a PDO object, `$login` is a PDOStatement.

Comment: Sidenote: `compte_pwd_md5 = '{$pass}'` - MD5, really? You're using PDO so you must be able to use `password_hash()`, which you should.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.  Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: it is to simplyfy I have some sha1 but I removed it when I post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add a column to your `COUNT` function. `COUNT` is a mysql function that returns the number of whatever parameter you pass it, so `COUNT(id)` would work.

Second, you must use the PDOStatement in order to fetch results. Replace

```
$reponse = $bdd->fetchColumn();
```

with

```
$reponse = $login->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Third, he have to use prepared satements with pdo, or there will be just no point in using pdo at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense do you have a documentation about prepared statement ? Thank you for your help

Comment: thank you very much you are very helpfull to me. I'm beginner here :)